# Winform AutoEllipsis Width

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I have a Winform label control with AutoEllipsis set to True.  The label itself has a max size set and AutoSize set to false.

When text extends the width of the label an ellipsis is displayed (...) and a tool tip appears on hover.  This is great but the resulting toolip is too long.  Is there anyway to control how the tooltip appears?  Ideally I'd like to set a max width on the actual tooltip and have the text wrap within it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can start a new line:

```
       this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button1, "Test 1" + System.Environment.NewLine + "Test 2");
```

I don't see any way to control the size. You could probably do it with an Owner draw version, there are some examples of Owner Drawn tooltip controls available on the web...